# Convert 19 digit Timestamp to Date time using PHP

Tags: php, timestamp

I am using Cloudflare API to fetch their LOGS. These logs contain 19 digit timestamp , example "timestamp": 1504838746369000000

i want to convert it into "YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s"

any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time appears to be in nanoseconds. Divide by 1.000.000.000 (`10e-9`) to get time in seconds:

```
<?php
$t = 1504838746369000000/1000000000;
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $t); // 2017-09-08 04:45:46
```